# Angular JQuery timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am shifting from jQuery to Angular. In jQuery we used this http://timepicker.co/
as firefox does not allow HTML5 input time.

I was trying to find the same timepicker for angular (As some of our past data and styles were based on this time picker). But I could not find one.

I dont know how to convert that time picker into directive or some other sort like that.

We need to use the same timepicker. (because our manager) I have seen some other time pickers available in angular.
Can you help ?

Comment: Try http://demo.jankuri.com/ngTimepicker/

Comment: It sounds as if you've looked at other timepickers -- any reason why those don't suit you?

Comment: No technical reasons but design document of team states a flat design of that type. They thing it suits more to the customers and the overall website design.

Comment: Not hard to wrap a jQuery plugin into a directive. Directive exposes element and just do `element.plugin()`

Answer (score 0):

try:
EasyTimepicker Directive
A timepicker directive that allows a user to select a time via a dropdown widget.

Click the buttons to increment/decrement hours & minutes or scroll with your mouse.

It's also smart enough to convert invalid input such as '1a' into '1:00 AM'

Built with the awesome AngularJS. Utilizes Bootstrap 3 styling.

Install
Usage
Configuration
The following options can be set either through data attributes on the time input or by overriding the EasyTimepickerConfig constant.

[Demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/uA3Ide?p=preview](http://ngmodules.org/modules/easy-timepicker)